# Gradle multi project build from Docker is failing, spring - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework

Tags: docker, spring-boot, gradle

I am trying to build jars for multi-project.
Folder tree structure:

- ROOT_FOLDER
- MICRO_SERVICE_1

  - SRC
  - BUILD.GRADLE (inside microservice_1)

```html
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.4.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com.impact'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


ext {
    springCloudVersion = 'Finchley.SR1'
}


dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client')
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    compile 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.9.0'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    compile 'org.modelmapper:modelmapper:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-ses'
    compile 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine'
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}

bootJar {
    mainClassName = 'com.impact.authservice.AuthServiceApplication'
}
```

ROOT LEVEL BUILD.GRADLE FILE

- BUILD.GRADLE

```html
plugins {
  id 'application'
  id 'java'
  id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '2.0.4'
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'application'
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'


    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    ext {
        impactVersion = '1.0.0'
        commitTimestamp = {
            return "git log -1 --pretty=format:%cd --date=format:%Y%m%d%H%M%S".execute().text.trim()
        }
        commitId = {
            return "git rev-parse --short HEAD".execute().text.trim()
        }
        buildId = {
            if (System.getenv("BUILD_ID") != null) return ".${System.getenv("BUILD_ID")}"
            else return ""
        }
    }

    group = 'com.impact'
    version = System.getenv("APP_VERSION") ?: "${commitTimestamp()}.${commitId()}${buildId()}"
    sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
    mainClassName = 'org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher'

    dependencies {
    }

    task copyDeps(type: Copy) {
        from (configurations.runtime + configurations.testRuntime) exclude '*'
        into '/tmp'
    }

    test {
        testLogging {
            events "passed", "skipped", "failed"
        }
        reports {
            junitXml.enabled = true
            junitXml.destination = file("${rootProject.projectDir}/build/test-results/junit")
            html.enabled = false
        }
    }
}

shadowJar {
    destinationDir = file("${rootProject.projectDir}/build/jars")
    classifier = 'fat'
}


wrapper {
    gradleVersion = '4.8'
}
```

Technology & Tools:

- Spring Boot
- Spring Cloud
- Gradle
- Makefile
- Docker
- Intellij

Project Description:

I have a few micro services build with spring boot and spring cloud.

The code is fine, an application is running fine on localhost.

Current state:

When I run "Gradle build" from root folder build is successful and by default, build folder is generated for each folder of micro-services.

Jar files work fine, the application is working correctly.

Now I am putting micro-services into docker container.

Dockerfile:

```html
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
MAINTAINER Me
LABEL application=test-dev

# Install system dependencies
RUN echo "http://nl.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing/" >> /etc/apk/repositories && \
    apk update && \
    apk add --no-cache bash libstdc++ nodejs nodejs-npm git && \
    npm install yarn -g

# Install common dependencies
COPY gradle /app/gradle
COPY build.gradle settings.gradle gradlew /app/
WORKDIR /app/
RUN chmod +x /app/gradlew && \
    ./gradlew copyDeps

# Install module dependencies
COPY microservice_1/build.gradle /app/microservice_1/
COPY microservice_2/build.gradle /app/microservice_2/


# App version and App sourses
ARG app_version
ENV APP_VERSION=${app_version}
COPY microservice_1 /app/microservice_1
COPY gateway /app/gateway
COPY microservice_2 /app/microservice_2
```

docker-compose.yml file:

```html
version: '3'

services:
  test:
    build:
      context: ../../
      dockerfile: docker/test/Dockerfile
      args:
        app_version: ${APP_VERSION}
    command:
    - /app/gradlew
    - clean
    - test
    - shadowJar
```

To build dockerfile and generate jar file I use a makefile.

This command will build dockerfile and try to copy the build folder from docker container into the root location of my project.

make file snippet:

```html
test:
 ${INFO} "Building images..."
 @ docker-compose $(TEST_ARGS) build test
 ${INFO} "Running tests..."
 @ docker-compose $(TEST_ARGS) up test
 @ mkdir -p $(TEST_DIR)
 ${INFO} "Removing existing artefacts..."
 @ rm -rf build
 ${INFO} "Copying build artefacts..."
 @ docker cp $$(docker-compose $(TEST_ARGS) ps -q test):/app/build/. build
 ${INFO} "Test complete"
```

Actual State:

All the jars from each microservices are generated into build folder located on my root folder

Desired State:
Jars should be executable and work the same way as they are when running "Gradle build" on my machine.

Problem occurred:

When I'm trying to run generated jars there is an error:

**spring - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework**

15 hours have passed since I tried to solve it, I feel that there is a problem with a root level gradle.build file with the main class declaration.

**mainClassName = 'org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher'**

Question:

1. Is this line of code is overriding mainClassName that is declared in each microservice folder and that's the issue?
2. Why declarations of mainClassName in each microservice folders are not taken into consideration when jar files are built from the root level of the project.

Thanks in advance for any kind of input:)